# NSIS Get Product Version solution failing

Tags: nsis

I have been trying to use the system calls GetFileVersionInfo and VerQueryValue to get the product version of an exe. I am using a legacy NSIS v2.0b3 (lots of scripts already in use and just wanting to make one little change).

After searching for a while I saw this solution
[Product version string from an exe - nsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707235/product-version-string-from-an-exe-nsis)
...but am having problems getting it to work sensibly.

The main call seems to work... ie

```
System::Call 'VERSION::GetFileVersionInfo(tr3,i,ir4,ir5)i.r0'
MessageBox MB_OK "GetFileVersionInfo returned dwLen=[$4] and lpData=[$5] for the block of Version Info"
```

...shows a sensible ptr in $5.
The next call is where things go wrong...

```
System::Call 'VERSION::VerQueryValue(ir5,t"\",*i.r6,*i.r7)i.r0'
StrCmp $0 0 fail
MessageBox MB_OK "VS_FIXEDFILEINFO returned as lplpBuffer=[$6] and PUINT=[$7]"
```

This call returns 0,0 for $6 and $7. And then of course the parsing fails...

```
;;---Parse buffer at $6 (lplp)
System::Call '*$6(i,i,i,i,i.r2,i.r1)'
MessageBox MB_OK "Read data from struct @$6: skip 4 ints then ints are dwProductVersionMS:[$2] dwProductVersionLS:[$1]"
```

...returns 0,0.

I'm thinking the problem is the indirect pointer in $6 here.
That is, $6 is type
   LPVOID  *lplpBuffer
....so I think the syntax of the call to set the value of $6 may need to be different.

Any help welcome... I tried some variations without success.

===Following request posted, here is the latest of many variations I have tried... hopefully that will help clarify what I am doing===

```
Function GetDllProductVersion
; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616470/nsis-get-product-version?rq=1
; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707235/product-version-string-from-an-exe-nsis slightly different System::Call's, but also later nsis not compatible

    ;;System::Store S   ;;;removed this and the matching Store L, as that crashes
    Pop $3

;;  System::Call 'VERSION::GetFileVersionInfoSize(tr3,*i)i.r4'
;;  MessageBox MB_OK "GetFileVersionInfoSize gets size [$4]"        ; cannot get a sensible answer, returns "error" in $4

    ;;---allocate block, address into $5
    StrCpy $4 0
    IntOp $4 $4 + 10000     ; set $4 to 10000
    System::Call '*(&i$4,t""r1,t""r2)i.r5' ; Set $1 and $2 to "" so they are empty if we fail
    MessageBox MB_OK "System::Call allocs [$4] bytes at addr [$5], next call GetFileVersionInfo"
    StrCmp $4 0 fail
    StrCmp $5 0 fail

    ;;---GetFileVersionInfo now-----
    System::Call 'VERSION::GetFileVersionInfo(tr3,i,ir4,ir5)i.r0'       ;; ir5 not isr5 ?? diff between solutions
    StrCmp $0 0 fail
    MessageBox MB_OK "GetFileVersionInfo returned dwLen=[$4] and lpData=[$5] for the block of Version Info"

    ;;---Now we get the VS_FIXEDFILEINFO structure using $5.... $6 will be lplpBuffer for it and $7 will be PUINT ptr to size of data in lplpBuffer
    System::Call 'VERSION::VerQueryValue(ir5,t"\",*i.r6,*i.r7)i.r0'     ;; using &i.r6 etc, not *i.r6 gives 0,0 no good, go back to *
    StrCmp $0 0 fail
    MessageBox MB_OK "VS_FIXEDFILEINFO returned as lplpBuffer=[$6] and PUINT=[$7]"

    ;;---Parse buffer at $6 (lplp)
    System::Call '**$6(i,i,i,i,i.r2,i.r1)'
    MessageBox MB_OK "Read data from struct @$6: skip 4 ints then ints are dwProductVersionMS:[$2] dwProductVersionLS:[$1]"

    ;;;or?????
    System::Call '**$6(i,i,i,i,&i.r2,&i.r1)'
    MessageBox MB_OK "Read data using & from struct @$6: skip 4 ints then ints are dwProductVersionMS:[$2] dwProductVersionLS:[$1]"

fail:
System::Free $5

    MessageBox MB_OK "After System::Free [$5]"
Push $1
Push $2
;;System::Store L       ;;;this crashes!!! so push and pop indiv registers used
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Please confirm your NSIS version. 2.0b3 was released in 2003! If you can't use NSIS v3 (why?), at least use v2.51.

Comment: The code you posted is not the same as the thing you liked to. You should post your complete code so that people can actually compile and test your problematic code!

Comment: ...post more code. Where do you allocate $5? I'm not going to bother investigating this if you can't post a complete function.

Comment: OK, will try to post latest version I tried... lots of variations.
Reason for using 2.0b3 is a small edit was made to get unzips timezone independent. I know... could migrate everything to a later NSIS, but I think the problem here is the calling of the function returned the lplpBuffer ptr.

Comment: After 3am in my timezone... thanks for quick responses so far and I will certainly be back online in 6 hours or so... look fwd to comments, thanks

Comment: Are you really using a 15 year old **BETA** version? System::Store failing is a red flag! Seriously consider upgrading.

Comment: You actually linked to the wrong SO question which is why I kept asking for example code. I believe you meant to link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616470/nsis-get-product-version and not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707235/product-version-string-from-an-exe-nsis

Comment: OK, point taken. I will try 2.51 and if problem goes away, I will try to apply the little patch needed in our environment (to do with timezone invariant unzipping when files are put into an installer in one timezone and unpacked in another). Who knows, maybe that issue is gone too which would make a rebuild 2.51 unnecessary. Will report back in a day or two. Thanks

YES code is based on the 34616470 link, see comment line at start of full post. Sorry for confusion... I tried to look at differences vs the other link while experimenting in vain to make it work.

Comment: I actually downloaded 2.0b3 and yes, it does not work there. Probably System plug-in changes but there is no reason to use beta software that is that old. Most code written by me will target NSIS 3 but most of it can probably work in 2.51 as well but not <= 2.0.

Comment: OK thanks again for help on this. I have downloaded 2.51 and will certainly update. I will do a separate post to talk about the timezone invariance change we need. I have looked at the src of 2.51 now and I can see the same change would likely be able to be applied ok to 2.51, and appreciate a lot of development has gone in since the very old version I was using. Thanks for pinpointing the problem, and hopefully this discussion and my annotated code is also useful for others trying to understand the tricky system api calls in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why `System::Store` crashes, it is documented to work even in v2.0b3. Then again, you are using 15 year old **beta** software so you can't expect everything to work correctly. Could be related to bug #1620178 which was fixed in v2.23 (11 years ago).

Your main issue is that v2.0b3 does not automatically support function names suffixed with `A` (most functions that take/return a string). It seems like support for this was added in v2.0b4.

You can modify the code you found to be compatible by hardcoding the suffix:

```
Function GetDllProductVersion
Exch $3
Push $1
Push $2
Exch 2
Push $4
Push $5
Push $6
Push $7
Push $0
System::Call 'VERSION::GetFileVersionInfoSizeA(tr3,*i)i.r4'
System::Call '*(&i$4,t""r1,t""r2)i.r5' ; Set $1 and $2 to "" so they are empty if we fail
StrCmp $4 0 fail
StrCmp $5 0 fail
    System::Call 'VERSION::GetFileVersionInfoA(tr3,i,ir4,ir5)i.r0'
    StrCmp $0 0 fail
    System::Call 'VERSION::VerQueryValueA(ir5,t"\",*i.r6,*i.r7)i.r0'
    StrCmp $0 0 fail
    System::Call '*$6(i,i,i,i,i.r2,i.r1)'
fail:
System::Free $5
Pop $0
Pop $7
Pop $6
Pop $5
Pop $4
Pop $3
Exch $1
Exch
Exch $2
FunctionEnd


Section
!define DllName "c:\windows\system32\ComCtl32.dll"

Push "${DllName}"
Call GetDllProductVersion
Pop $R0
Pop $R1
IntOp $R2 $R0 / 0x00010000
IntOp $R3 $R0 & 0x0000FFFF
IntOp $R4 $R1 / 0x00010000
IntOp $R5 $R1 & 0x0000FFFF
DetailPrint 'ProdVer: $R2.$R3.$R4.$R5'
SectionEnd
```

but I would strongly recommend that you upgrade to a more recent version. v2.51 as a minimum to get all security fixes.

Comment: THANKS... and will certainly upgrade to v2.51 for security fixes and reduction in other surprises going forward.
As I said, I will need to rebuild with the little tweak for NSIS to save/restore time zone invariant filetime stamps, when installer is built in one timezone and deployed in another. We needed to be compatible with WinZip timestamps when extracting files from a regular zip/exe. We're just converting to and from UTC time within the installer, two little changes - in exec.c and script.cpp. Can post another question and link to that later.

Comment: And at last I have tried to update my "datefixed" NSIS to the latest version, as promised. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275362/updating-nsis-to-preserve-filetimes-when-unpacking-in-a-different-timezone)  ...thanks @Anders